# Bat file to change autoconfing setting

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wifi, netsh

I'm trying to setup 1 batch file to turn the netsh wlan autoconfig setting on and off, at the moment I have something setup like this

```
netsh wlan set autoconfig | FIND "enabled=no" /I /C
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
  netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=yes interface="Wi-Fi"
  echo DISABLED
) else (
  netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=no interface="Wi-Fi"
  echo ENABLED
)

pause
```

however it seems that `netsh wlan set autoconfig` doesn't tell me what the current setting is so FIND will never return the correct thing. Is there a better way to get if it is on or off? Thanks in advance!

Comment: had a look at `netsh wlan show autoconfig` maybe?

Comment: Ah show tells me if it's enabled or disabled and I can FIND from that, I had no clue show worked for that, thanks a bunch!